# Is it possible to set when a cookie expires inside an integration test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, testing, cookies, integration-testing

Is there a way in integration tests to manipulate a cookie's expiration date (as to test if it is taken into account properly). For example, if `cookies['user_id']` already exists in the test, manipulate it like this:

```
cookies['user_id'].expires = Time.zone.now - 1.day
```

(this returns `undefined method 'expires='`)
I'm using MiniTest in Rails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [TimeCop](https://github.com/travisjeffery/timecop) to time travel in your test:

```
def setup
  do_something_which_sets_cookie
  Timecop.freeze(1.month.from_now) 
  # or how ever long it takes the cookie to expire
end

def teardown 
  Timecop.return
end
```

This can be a nice approach if what you want to test is how your application behaves after a period of time without tying the test to the implementation details.

Otherwise you simply need to ensure that the cookie exists before setting the expiry:

```
cookies['user_id'].expires = Time.zone.now - 1.day if cookies['user_id']
```

Comment: Thanks @max, I'd like to look at TimeCop later and first try your last line. However, it doesn't seem to work. `cookies['remember_token']` returns `"Vp8FxZSymqttPLN7S6wcA"`, so the cookie exists. But `cookies['remember_token'].expires = Time.zone.now - 1.day` returns the error `undefined method 'expires=' for "Vp8FxZSymqttPLN7S6wcA":String`.

Comment: I haven't really worked with cookies in rails but have you tried setting the cookie with a hash like in the docs: `cookies['remember_token'] = { value: cookies['remember_token'], expires:  Time.zone.now - 1.day }`. I believe that can't manipulate a cookie in place - you need to issue the client a new cookie. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Cookies.html